# Torrent caching

Tags: cache, torrent

I am looking for torrent caching software (like SQUID for http). Do you know any?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanisms for doing this are now built into the bittorrent protocol:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_Discovery_Protocol

However as mentioned in the article, to date no specs have been released to allow support.

Answer (score 1):

[PeerApp](http://www.peerapp.com/Technology/VideoCaching.aspx) can do that but probably doesn't suit the scale you are looking at.

How many torrent users and what bandwidth/volume do you want to apply the cache to?  What platform do you want to run it on?  Do you need to handle a specific torrent app/protocol, and be able to cache SSL torrent downloads?

Answer (score 0):

The BitTorrent application supports caching. In fact, my ISP caches most torrents. The version of BitTorrent that my ISP uses is 7.7, and I get quite high speeds, i.e. 8-12mbps.

how do I know my ISP uses it?

1. My ISP does not have any package with such a high upload speed, 8-12mbps, maximum upload is 2mbps
2. The IP of the cache server is usually the same, and from that single IP, I get over 90% of data at 99% of my full ADSL2 speed.